# there is a problem of finding revenue for a company on its discounted prices

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
for value in df['discounted_price']:
    if value > 600:
        df['net_revenue'] = df['discounted_price'] * 0.25
    elif (value <=600) and (value >350):
        df['net_revenue'] = df['discounted_price'] * 0.15
    elif (value <=350) & (value >100):
        df['net_revenue'] = df['discounted_price'] * 0.10
    else: 
        df['net_revenue'] = df['discounted_price'] * 0.50
print('Net_revenue')
```

This is the code for finding revenue for some items and printing it in a column.
The loop only iterates over the first value. What is the problem with this code? What do I have to do to run this over all values?

Comment: Each time through the loop, you're reassigning the `df['net_revenue']` entire column.  So at the end of the loop, `df['net_revenue']` will be whatever definition was made on the final loop iteration.

Comment: It seems like you thought you were assigning each _item_ in the column, but that's not what the code does.  It replaces the _entire_ column.

Comment: Do you mind producing a [mcve]?

Comment: @john-gordon    How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a vectorized conditional logic assignment such as [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
import numpy as np
...

conditions = [
    df['discounted_price'] > 600,
    (df['discounted_price'] > 350) & (df['discounted_price'] <= 600),
    df['discounted_price'] <= 350
]

values = [
    df['discounted_price'] * 0.25,
    df['discounted_price'] * 0.15,
    df['discounted_price'] * 0.10
]

df['net_revenue'] = np.select(
    conditions, values, df['discounted_price'] * 0.50
)
```

**Demo**

```py
### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(862022)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': np.random.choice(['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia'], 500),
    'discounted_price': np.random.normal(500, 500, 500)
})

### CALCULATIONS
conditions = [
    random_df['discounted_price'] > 600,
    (random_df['discounted_price'] > 350) & (random_df['discounted_price'] <= 600),
    random_df['discounted_price'] <= 350
]

values = [
    random_df['discounted_price'] * 0.25,
    random_df['discounted_price'] * 0.15,
    random_df['discounted_price'] * 0.10
]

random_df['net_revenue'] = np.select(conditions, values)
random_df['net_revenue'] = random_df['net_revenue'].fillna(
    random_df['discounted_price'] * 0.50
)
random_df['net_revenue2'] = np.select(
    conditions, values, random_df['discounted_price'] * 0.50
)

random_df.head(10)
#     group  discounted_price  net_revenue  net_revenue2
# 0   stata        326.517674    32.651767     32.651767
# 1   stata        426.097043    63.914556     63.914556
# 2  python       1508.041798   377.010450    377.010450
# 3  python       1197.088419   299.272105    299.272105
# 4     sas       1255.796380   313.949095    313.949095
# 5     sas        129.319099    12.931910     12.931910
# 6   stata        314.035189    31.403519     31.403519
# 7    spss         28.192324     2.819232      2.819232
# 8     sas        613.413668   153.353417    153.353417
# 9  python         58.468541     5.846854      5.846854

random_df['net_revenue'].equals(random_df['net_revenue2'])
# True
```

Comment: it shows the following error                                                                                           ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I think `default` in `np.select` has to be a scalar value

Comment: Try edited answer using `fillna` for your else condition.

Comment: is it not possible to solve this problem using loop?

Comment: Did edit work for you? Yes, you can solve by looping through all rows but this is often very inefficient and not recommended in data frame/matrix operations in Python and beyond (R, Julia, SQL, etc.) that can carry millions of rows. Vectorization scales well and is the preferred method of calculations.

Comment: still it shows the same error as above.

Comment: See edit using parentheses to wrap the two logic statements of second condition. Demo is also included showing actual output. Also, @rhug123, you can use a Series in *default* argument of `numpy.select` though OP's *else* is unnecessary unless `discounted_price` is missing but multiplying it by 0.5 is also missing!

Comment: I  just tried to do as in  the demo. But facing the same error again...even I tried the demo itself..but showing this error  :ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().                                                    why this error occurs?

Comment: What version of pandas are you running: `pd.__version__`? Consider upgrading to latest 1.4 as bug fixes may have resolved the error you encounter: `pip install pandas --upgrade`.

Comment: I  tried the demo again. It worked for the Demo. But didn't worked for my actual data. I don't know which version is running. Ok I will check and upgrade it. Thank you.